# Как записать функцию СУММПРОИЗВ в макросе

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

```
Sub СуммПроизв()
   For i = 4  to 60
      Cells(i, 7) = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Range(Cells(1, 17), Cells(1, 80)), Range(Cells(i, 17), Cells(i, 80)))
   Next i
```

так не работает

Answer (score 1):

Это особенность применения данной функции. При расчете `SUMPRODUCT` в `VBA` конструкция `Range(cells(),cells())`не работает. Но диапазон можно записать по-другому:

```
Range(столбец & строка & ":" & столбец & строка)
```

В этом случае функция отработает корректно:

```
Sub СуммПроизв()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 4 To 60
        Cells(i, 7) = Application.SumProduct(Range("Q" & i & ":CB" & i), Range("Q" & i & ":CB" & i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Но в целом подход неправильный. Вызов функций листа в коде - процесс медленный. Если уж применяется `VBA`, то и считать можно только своими средствами:

```
Sub SumProduct_()
    Dim aData(), aResult()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    aData = Range("Q4:CB60").Value
    ReDim aResult(1 To UBound(aData), 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
        For j = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
            aResult(i, 1) = aResult(i, 1) + aData(i, j) ^ 2
        Next j
    Next i

    Range("G4").Resize(UBound(aData), 1).Value = aResult
End Sub
```

На небольших диапазонах выигрыш по времени при замене функции листа на обработку в массиве практически незаметен.

Comment: На больших или на небольших? За счёт чего получается выигрыш?

Comment: Чем больше диапазон, тем медленнее обработка в коде с вызовом функций листа

Comment: Неужели они внутри не оптимизированы?

Comment: Протестировал. На 50k строк код с массивами отработал за 2,39 сек. sumproduct - 6.21 cек. Большую задержку дает не сама функция, а постоянное обращение к листу - на каждом шаге цикла заполняется ячейка. Ели сделать заполнение массива функцией и лист вызывать только два раза, скорость  обработки такого же диапазона намного выше 2,84 сек. Вообще, функции листа (если они в ячейках), работают быстрее аналогичной обработки в макросе. Но, опять же - чем больше ячеек с формулами, тем тяжелее книга..

Comment: Спасибо, интересно.

Comment: Да, интересно. Функции листа написаны на каком-то из С и, если находятся на своем месте (на листе), то и работают быстрее, чем аналог на VBA. Но если функция вызывается из VBA... Внутренней кухни не знаю. Возможно , и там функции листа не теряют своей шустрости. Но пока VBA надумает обратиться к приложению, пока Application надумает ответить и передать функцию... А микросекунды тикают )

Comment: Просто я как раз думал про накладные расходы на вызов, но тогда странно, что они зависят от объёма данных.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106775/discussion-between-vikttur-and-qwertiy).